# :not selector isn't recognizing classes

Tags: html, css

```css
.titlebar {
  justify-content: baseline;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: -2px;
  height: 125px;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: 2;
}

.titlebar:not(.join) {
  display: flex;
}

.login,
.join {
  float: right;
  display: inline-flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div 
  onclick="window.location='join.php';" 
  id="join" 
  class="join" 
  style=" color: black; border-radius: 5px;">
  Join
</div>
<div 
  onclick="window.location='login.php';" 
  id="login" 
  class="login">
  Log In
</div>
```

I'm trying to use `:not` to exclusively align `.login` and `.join` on the right. When I try it with element types like `div`, it works as all elements in my bar are `div`s, but it does not recognize `.login`, `.join`, or any other class I used to test. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read [ask] and describe your problem before showing code. Please also remove the excessive leading indentation from your code block (see [What should I keep out of my posts and titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131009/997587)).

Comment: Please look carefully at your snippet as there are some problems. For example the color of login is white so we don’t see it, and titlebar doesn’t exist.